# GCC Default Link -l

Tags: gcc

When I need to use, for example, the gnu function gsl_sf_bessel_J0 in a program, I simply compile it with gcc -lgsl -o gsl_test.c gsl_test. Why do I have to include -lgsl for it to work? Is there any way I can set it as a default so I don't have to type it out everytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile with the `-v` flag, you'll see the command the GCC front-end invokes to link your final executable*. If your program uses a function like `gsl_sf_bessel_J0` that isn't in one of the default libraries (possibly limited to `libc` and maybe also `libm`), you need to explicitly link it.

If you don't like typing it all the time, make a simple Makefile. Your case is simple enough that you can handle it with just environment variables, actually:

```
$ export CC=gcc
$ export LDLIBS=-lgsl
$ make gsl_test
gcc     gsl_test.c  -lgsl -o gsl_test
$
```

`make`'s default built-in rules will do the rest.

*: for reference, my compiler links your example as:

```
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" 
  -demangle 
  -dynamic 
  -arch x86_64 
  -macosx_version_min 10.12.0 
  -o gsl_test 
  /var/folders/cp/wvm69p1n7_bbjpxxqmttwn700000gn/T/gsl_test-0afe3a.o 
  -lgsl 
  -lSystem    
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```